# Connecting Microsoft Access database (.accdb) to QGIS

Tags: qgis, database

I am trying to connect a database to a QGIS map for a project. I've managed to set up the Access/ODBC connection using the ODBC Data Source Administrator, but when I try to add a new database connection in QGIS I get the following error:

[image]

"Connection failed - Check settings and try again.
Extended Error information:
Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for XXXXX
[Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The database you are trying to open requires a newer version of Microsoft Access."

I would update to the newest version of Access, except that I am already using it.
I am using the latest version of Access 2016 (16.0.9029.2106) -32 bit
Microsoft Access database engine 2016 -32 bit
ODBC Administrator -32 bit
QGIS 2.18.16 - 32 bit
Windows 10

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: For the dsn, are you sure you selected the Access driver supporting accdb?

Comment: Do you have any "large number" data types in your Access database?

Comment: If the error message is incorrectly telling you to get a newer version of Access, it would be worth submitting a bug report. https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've since found that this appears to be an issue with Access 2016 and ODBC connections see: [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_win10-mso_o365b/microsoft-access-2016-the-database-you-are-trying/53d694eb-cf55-4c90-a30e-a70c30e79f09)